# How do I write multiple values to a redshift table from a pcollection

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift, apache-beam

So I have a template that write a single strings to a redshift table as a record.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Step 1: Create Options
        Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);

        // Step 2: Create Pipeline
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        // Step 3: Create PCollection from array of random words <Strings>
        PCollection<String> collection = pipeline
                .apply(Create.of(Arrays.asList("start", "test", "case", "single", "end")))
                .setCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of());

        // Step 4: Execute transforms on the collection. This transform writes the string value to a table named 'test'
        collection.apply(JdbcIO.<String>write()
                .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration
                        .create("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver", options.getRedshiftUrl())
                        .withUsername(options.getUser()).withPassword(options.getPassword()))
                .withStatement("insert into example_schema.test values (?)")
                .withPreparedStatementSetter(new JdbcIO.PreparedStatementSetter<String>() {
                    public void setParameters(String element, PreparedStatement query) throws SQLException {
                        query.setString(1, element);
                    }
                }));

        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }
```

I want to adapt this to take write multiple fields of consisting of integers, doubles and strings.

I've picked that there's quite a few issues with my approach but I feel I may be randomly trying to bump into the correct implementation without fully understanding the process

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Step 1: Create Options
        Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);

        String insertQuery = "insert into sample.mytable (item_int, item_string, item_double" +
                "values (?, ?, ?)";

        CustomObj custom_obj = new CustomObj(1, "", 0.5);

        // Step 2: Create Pipeline
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        // Step 3: Create PCollection from array of random words <Strings>
        PCollection<CustomObj> collection = pipeline
                .apply(Create.of());

        // Step 4: Execute transforms on the collection. This transform writes the string value to a table named 'test'
        collection.apply(JdbcIO.<CustomObj>write()
                .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration
                        .create("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver", options.getRedshiftUrl())
                        .withUsername(options.getUser()).withPassword(options.getPassword()))
                .withStatement(insertQuery)
                .withPreparedStatementSetter(new JdbcIO.PreparedStatementSetter<CustomObj>() {
                    public void setParameters(CustomObj element, PreparedStatement query) throws SQLException {
                        query.setInt(1, element.intVal);
                        query.setString(2, element.stringVal);
                        query.setDouble(3, element.doubleVal);
                    }
                }));
        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }


    public static class CustomObj
    {
        private Integer intVal;
        private String stringVal;
        private Double doubleVal;

        public CustomObj (Integer intVal, String stringVal, Double doubleVal)
        {
            this.intVal = intVal;
            this.stringVal = stringVal;
            this.doubleVal = doubleVal;
        }
    }
```

I understand so far that I need to set an appropriate coder for my PCollection which I'm unsure about given the object type I am using.

I'm also failing to make use of PreparedStatementSetter correctly as well but when I search for clarity I get examples that use a different approach altogether.

I know my issue might be a little vague but I'd appreciate it if I could be directed to a source that will offer more clarity with respect to the approach I've shown above.

The output this produces is

```
 no suitable method found for of(no arguments)
[ERROR]     method org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create.<T>of(java.lang.Iterable<T>) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
[ERROR]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[ERROR]     method org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create.<T>of(T,T...) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
[ERROR]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[ERROR]     method org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create.<K,V>of(java.util.Map<K,V>) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) K,V
[ERROR]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Okay, so working from the original template, I instead opted to combine the query arguments into a string and then parse them appropriately when setting the query parameters after splitting that string. I'm sure there's a better way to do this though so I'll continue looking into it

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the compiler failed to pick the right overload of `Create.of()`. If you look at the doc for [`Create`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Create.html) there is no overload that takes zero arguments, you have to pass either an iterable, a map, or varargs with non-optional first argument. You probably meant `Create.of(custom_obj)`, which should work as you would expect it to (in this case it will create a `PCollection<CustomObj>` with a single element in it).

The statement setter should also work as you have it, here's an example that does the same thing: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/41478d00d34598e56471d99d0845ac16efa5b8ef/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIOTest.java#L479